# SVN(Subversion) decreases system/application performance?

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

Before using SVN for the application,the application was running smoothly.To centralize the system we started using SVN for the application ,since then application became slow.So I inferred that it is due to SVN.Or maybe I am wrong.
So my question is Do SVN decreases system/application performance?

```
Application server is Tomcat 6

Subversion -TortoiseSVN 1.6.9
```

Comment: How are you using SVN? To store your application code? Or does your application code access SVN?

Comment: Did you consider using `git` ?

Comment: I wonder if you are having typo.  SVN is for storing source code, after building from your source, your APPLICATION runs by itself and  have nothing to do with SVN.  Unless you APPLICATION is something so special that use SVN internally for storing application data.  However in such case you should state clearly in your question

Comment: @AdrianShum I commit my changes from development environment to SVN and the code which is on tomcat server is also connected to SVN,from there I update the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"SVN decreases system/application performance" is right according to network connection, synchronize checkouts,synchronize uses,etc with many machines.But you can control your subvserion performance. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-svnbins/index.html) is SVN performance tuning article from IBM.Learn it.